# Completely stop sprite on collision

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am building a game where the player sprite bounces around the GameScene. When the user taps the screen, the player sprite should stick to the next wall it hits. How can I completely remove all the energy from the sprite so that it no longer moves?

What attributes should I change? I have tried setting:

```
restitution() = 0
```

but this does not help.

I am looking for an answer for SpriteKit in Swift.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are talking about a node's velocity. It's dx and dy values to be exact.

```
yourNode.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake( 0, 0 )
```

the above will set your node's x and y axis velocity to zero.